# jquery - How to fade in and fading out back an element (div) as we scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I am so new to Jquery and Javascript. I know there are bunch of exact same post or question but non of it works or I'm just to blind to use it.

My aim is to fade in a div as we scroll down, as we scroll down at a certain point I want to fade out back the div and another div fade in. Of cause there is no problem to fade in but to fadeout back is a problem. There are 6 sequence of div that i want to apply. The first div works fine as I scroll down on 2100 i want to fade it out and the next div will fade in which work pretty well.

the sequence div id is #header1 and so on and I set the #header2 to #header6 display to none in CSS.
Is there any way to make it fade in just on the range of the windows or something. thanks a lot

here is some of the script that i try but it doesn't work

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2100) {
     $('#header1').fadeOut();
 }
 else {
     $('#header1').fadeIn();
 } });

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2100) {
     $('#header2').fadeIn();
 }
 else if ($(window).scrollTop() > 3500) {
     $('#header2').fadeOut();
 }
 else {
     $('#header2').fadeOut();
 } });

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 3500) {
     $('#header3').fadeIn();
 }
 else {
     $('#header3').fadeOut();
 } });
```

Comment: use CSS3 opacity transition and calculate the ratio for the alpha. 2100 = 100%, 3500 = 0%

Comment: you got my attention, how do I use CSS3 transition without using jquery. I google it and most of it the CSS opacity transition happen by hovering mouse over it, how do i make the transition as the user on a certain position of the page.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp and post some code, go from here. It's basically changing the CSS like you would do with anything else. You can also use a standard opacity property if you don't mind about hardware acceleration.

Comment: With this you can give all headers a common class, it will hide them when out of sight instead of fading but matches your description for the rest : http://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/avdyWx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this *correct me if I'm wrong* with this way you don't need to calculate where you need the .scrollTop().

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $( "#header" ).scrollTop())
```

Comment: the #header(div) position is fixed in css, forget to mention that. All the #header (div) is in order and i set display to none. So as i scroll all i want is the div to fade in fade out back one by one.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is this:

just picture the scroll even just fired , and you are  past 3500 ,

```
$('#header1').fadeOut();
 $('#header2').fadeIn();
$('#header2').fadeOut();
 $('#header3').fadeIn();
```

all execute at the exact same time , is that intended?  , you should have conditions checking if the scroll position is between 2 numbers

if your  2100 > scrollTop  < 3500 then:

```
 $('#header1').fadeOut();
 $('#header2').fadeIn();
  $('#header2').fadeOut();
   $('#header3').fadeOut();
```

all fire at the exact same time , and if you're below 2100 then:

```
   $('#header1').fadeIn();
  $('#header2').fadeOut();
    $('#header3').fadeOut();
```

all execute at the same time

Comment: what i did is `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2100 <3500) {
         $('#header2').fadeIn();
     }` and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 2100 <3500) { $('#header2').fadeIn(); }
```

will not work. You haven't written the if statement correctly.
You should be using code looking something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
if ( scrollTop > (2100) && scrollTop < (3500) ){
     $('#header1').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#header2').fadeout('slow');
     $('#header3').fadeOut('slow');
 }else{
     $('#header1').fadeOut('slow');
     $('#header2').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#header3').fadeIn('slow');
   }
});
```